# Cannot resolve symbol 'AnalyticsReporting'

Tags: java, google-analytics-api

I am trying to learn the usage of Google Analytics API. I am following the tutorial provided by "https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/service-java" and have copy pasted their code.
I have used the following dependency:

```
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-analytics</artifactId>
        <version>v3-rev20190807-1.32.1</version>
```

But I am facing three problems:

1. Cannot resolve method 'initializeAnalytics' in 'HelloAnalytics'
2. Cannot resolve symbol 'AnalyticsReporting'
3. Incompatible types. Found: 'com.google.api.services.analytics.Analytics', required: 'AnalyticsReporting'

The problems are bring faced in following areas:

```
 private static AnalyticsReporting initializeAnalytic() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {

    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential
            .fromStream(new FileInputStream(KEY_FILE_LOCATION))
            .createScoped(AnalyticsScopes.all());

    // Construct the Analytics service object.
    return new Analytics.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
}
```

and

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Analytics analytics = initializeAnalytics();

        String profile = getFirstProfileId(analytics);
        System.out.println("First Profile Id: "+ profile);
        printResults(getResults(analytics, profile));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Kindly let me know if I am making any mistake or if there is any solution available.